# Jquery Google map like plugin - Using custom maps/image and ability to add markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps, maps, customization

I have spent a while this evening searching for a good tutorial on how to use Google Maps with my own map image. I have an image that is basically a blue print and I need something similar to how the google maps works where you can drag it around, zoom in and most importantly position markers.

I have seen several things on using the Google Maps API to do something like this but all of them do not cover it very well or are outdated. Also a good chunk of them are just changing the colours of the existing maps or just positioning the existing map somewhere else, not actually completely replacing the map.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for this? Or perhaps a completely standalone jQuery plugin that can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know two:

- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)
- [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)

They both let you load data from arbitrary sources and use it as you'd do in a Google Map.

Comment: Thanks for this. Know of anything simpler? It basically needs to be just a static image that I can move around by dragging and the ability to position markers on the image. This creating tiles to be able to zoom properly seems a little over-kill.

Comment: nvm. Found out how to do it with OpenLayers. Should be able to do what I need now. Thanks!

Comment: Also found out how to do it on OpenLayers, although couldn't find the functionality in Leaflet